# Storing address of opening and closing of bracket

Tags: c

If the user gives me a string of any combination of brackets like `(()())` then I want a program which checks the opening and closing of the bracket and also stores the address of opening and closing of each bracket separately in an arranged way.  How can I do it?

Comment: Use a stack or a recursive call to keep track of nesting, and a list or similar to track the ordering.

Comment: Simply countup, countdown.

Comment: do any give me a typed code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of a type of bracket is one kind, it is not necessary to save something just by increasing or decreasing the counter.

Examples like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isBalanceBracket(const char *s){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; s[i] ; ++i){
        if(s[i] == '(')
            ++count;
        else if(s[i] == ')')
            if(--count < 0)
                return false;
    }
    return count == 0;
}

int main(void){
    const char *test[] = {
        "(()())", ")()(", "()))"
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test); ++i){
        if(isBalanceBracket(test[i]))
            printf("%s is OK\n", test[i]);
        else
            printf("%s is NG\n", test[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but how can I store the address of the opening and closing of bracket example if user enter (()()) then I want the address as 1,6  2,3  4,5 for each bracket

Comment: @NavinChauhan Why is that necessary? I think it is better to implement a stack.

Comment: i  want to remove the variables from the innermost bracket

Comment: @NavinChauhan I think that it is useless just to save the position(address). Because the position of the pair does not represent the depth of the brackets. It is better to create something like a syntax tree.